# How to convert a CGRect from portrait to landscape?

Tags: ios, iphone, rotation, cgrect

I would like to convert a CGRect frame that exists in a view of size 320 x 480 (portrait) to a view of size 640 x 480 (landscape left). I should note that I am testing on an iPhone 4S. However, I need to find a method generic enough for an iPhone 5, with a taller screen.

Here is some code which does a rotation:

```
CGFloat radians = -90 * (M_PI/180);
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
CGRect rotatedRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, rotation);

// Needs offset?
rotatedRect.origin.y += self.aView.frame.size.height;
// rotatedRect.origin.x += self.aView.frame.size.width;
```

I may also need a translation and scaling:

```
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(rect.size.height, 0.0);
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0); // what values to use?
CGAffineTransform centeredRotation = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
```

I'm open to any other method of converting the CGRect frames.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: How will it translate? Sam top left corner, same center point, other?

Comment: Let's go with translation using the center point. The ratios for the position and size will be identical. Thanks for responding.